# SharpSVN: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process

Tags: .net, svn, addition, sharpsvn

I'm using the SharpSVN .NET library.  This exception only occurs when adding a file, but not adding a folder.  Why would that be?

```
Can't open file 'D:\FOLDER\FILE.xls': The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
```

Here is the code.  It contains the folder logic and the file logic.

```
        SvnUpdateArgs updateArgs2 = new SvnUpdateArgs();
        updateArgs2.Depth = SvnDepth.Empty;
        client.Update("D:\FOLDER", updateArgs2);

        if (!Directory.Exists("D:\FOLDER"))
        {
            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory("D:\FOLDER");

            SvnAddArgs addArgs1 = new SvnAddArgs();
            addArgs1.Depth = SvnDepth.Empty;
            client.Add("D:\FOLDER", addArgs1);

            SvnCommitArgs commitArgs1 = new SvnCommitArgs();
            commitArgs1.LogMessage = GeneralService.GetCurrentUserWindowsLogin();
            client.Commit("D:\FOLDER", commitArgs1);
        }

        // update if exists, otherwise add it to working copy if it does not exist

        SvnUpdateArgs updateArgs3 = new SvnUpdateArgs();
        updateArgs3.Depth = SvnDepth.Empty;
        client.Update("D:\FOLDER\FILE.xls", updateArgs3);

        if (!File.Exists("D:\FOLDER\FILE.xls"))
        {
            System.IO.File.Create("D:\FOLDER\FILE.xls");

            SvnAddArgs addArgs1 = new SvnAddArgs();
            addArgs1.Depth = SvnDepth.Empty;
            client.Add("D:\FOLDER\FILE.xls", addArgs1);

            SvnCommitArgs commitArgs1 = new SvnCommitArgs();
            commitArgs1.LogMessage = GeneralService.GetCurrentUserWindowsLogin();
            client.Commit("D:\FOLDER\FILE.xls", commitArgs1);
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `system.io.file.create` it create an instance os system.io.stream coz it is a shared function.I suppose that you can fix it in a simple manner like this one.

```
  Dim F As System.IO.FileStream = System.IO.File.Create("piipo")
  ''release the stream
    F.Close()
```

Comment: Yep, that was it!  I just used a "using" statement to avoid two steps.  .. using (var fileStream = File.Open(@"D:\FOLDER\FILE.xls", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite)) { }